# OrientDB - Example for Traverse - BREADTH_FIRST

Tags: sql, orientdb, traversal

I read about Traverse [here](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Java-Traverse.html#traversing-strategies) and curious as how to use BREADTH_FIRST strategy in the SQL? Can anyone please some examples?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made this example for your case:

This is my schema:

[image]

The query:

```
traverse * from Number strategy breadth_first
```

The output:

[image]

Hope it helps